# Generic Data Validation in a generic transformation -Pentaho Kettle PDI

Tags: validation, pentaho, kettle

I have been trying to create a generic transformation  which can be used for preliminary data cleansing

What I have in mind is to get the input in some format (csv, table input, xml etc). Then have a dml file input in a JSON or XML format which will be read from and used to check the incoming data.

So when the input changes, I can pass a different dml file to check the data format and validity. I tried accomplishing this using the Data Validator step and it didn't work. I also tried the Modified Java script step, but it gave me ( the transformation cannot accept inputs with different schema) an error. Please find screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of the transformation]

Can this be accomplished in the first place. Am I missing something here. All help is much appreciated.

Comment: I've never used this step before, but my understanding is that the way you do this is with the `ETL Metadata Injection` step. Might give that a try.

Comment: Thanks,I tried using the ETL Metadata Injection step earlier, but it did not suit the requirement,do you have some reference which made you suggest this step?

Comment: Sorry, only the PDI documentation. That step is for that purpose of supplying different meta data to the same step, but it's limited. What version of PDI are you using?